# Sort data based on parent

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, powerquery

When I pull data into excel it comes out listed randomly. I therefore want to be able to sort the rows in the right order. Each row refer to a parent in the last cell to the right. Not all rows have parents.

I want to sort the data from this (See picture 1 below)

[image]

to this (see picture 2 below)

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the logic for the sort??

Comment: None of the columns appear to be sorted in the bottom picture...

Comment: See my answer below. Thanks for your help